# How to get distinct id and sum of quantities from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I execute this:

```
select
    (select sum(Flt_Fuel_Qty)
       from ful_fuel_issue_bills group by num_vehicle_number_id) as eachvehiclequantity,
    (SELECT concat(d.Str_Regn_Code , '-' , d.Str_Regn_Number) 
        FROM ful_vehicle_list_m d
     WHERE a.Num_Vehicle_Number_Id = d.Num_Vehicle_ID 
     group by a.num_vehicle_number_id) AS Vehicle_No
from
    ful_fuel_issue_bills a
```

but I get an error:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

How can I solve this?

I want the columns in the output as:

```
Vehicle No   Quantity
```

The `vehicle` table contains `num_vehicle_id`, `Str_Regn_Code`, `Str_Regn_Number`
 and the `bill` table contains `bill_id`, `num_vehicle_number_id`, `Flt_Fuel_Qty`

Comment: Please mention the relationship between these tables. If doesn't exist, then is there any mapping between these table?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (and should not) do this with sub-selects, because -- like the error message says -- they return more than one record per record produced from the main `from` clause.

Instead use a `join` in the `from` clause, like this:

```
select    sum(a.Flt_Fuel_Qty) as eachvehiclequantity,
          concat(d.Str_Regn_Code , '-' , d.Str_Regn_Number) AS Vehicle_No
from      ful_vehicle_list_m d 
left join ful_fuel_issue_bills a
       on a.Num_Vehicle_Number_Id = d.Num_Vehicle_ID 
group by  d.Num_Vehicle_ID
```

Comment: It may not make much difference but best practice suggests (and the latest version of MySQL requires) that you group on vehicle_no

Comment: @Strawberry, in the latest versions of MySql there there is an exception for [functionally dependent fields](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html), which is the case here, as we can assume `num_vehicle_id` is the primary key. So, I think this is OK.